# AngularJS - Como fechar uma modal $uibModal pai através de uma modal $uibModal filha?

Tags: angularjs, modal

Utilizo AngularJS no projeto.
Tenho uma modal que abre a partir de um botão da modal pai. Quero inserir um botão de cancelar na modal filha, que vai fechar as duas modais.

Comment: Como você chama a modal filha dentro da modal pai ? pode postar o código ?

Comment: Eu tenho uma modal que é chamada por uma função no controller. Essa modal chama outra modal, declarada em uma diretiva. Tenho como fechar as duas modais ao mesmo tempo? Da pra entender explicando assim? O código é gigantesco, não tenho como postar. A chamada dos modais é através do ng-click em buttons.

Comment: O que eu tô supondo e que você pode usar Promisses na ação de abrir a modal.

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo é pra abrir o modal pai:

```
    $scope.openDetailsModal = function(){
        $scope.orderModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/local/modals/details.html',
            scope: $scope,
            size: 'lg' 
    });

   $scope.orderModalInstance.result.then(function(){
            $scope.destroyOrderData();
        }).catch(function(e){
            $scope.destroyOrderData();
        });

    $scope.destroyOrderData = function(){
        $templateCache.remove($scope.orderModalInstance);
    }
```

Nessa página details.html, tem um botão que abre o modal filho:

```
$scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'app/' + ($attrs.layout == 'account' ? '' : 'local/') + 'views/modals/page.html',
    size: 'md',
    scope: $scope
});

$scope.isModalOpen = true;
$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function(){
    $scope.destroyData();
}).catch(function(e){
    $scope.destroyData();
});
```

A função destroyData:

```
$scope.destroyData = function(){
        $scope.isModalOpen = false;
        $templateCache.remove($scope.modalInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui utilizando $emit na função de fechar o modal filho e usando a função $on na diretiva que cria o modal pai, com a ação de fechar o modal pai.